# Why aren't Guava ImmutableCollections annotated @Immutable(containerOf = {"E"})

Tags: guava, immutability, errorprone

Why aren't all Guava `ImmutableCollection` classes, `ImmutableMap` classes, etc. annotated with `@Immutable(containerOf = {"E"})` (or the equivalent for each class's type parameter(s))?

The fully qualified annotation name is `com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable`.

Comment: Which `@Immutable` annotation are you speaking about? I know none [in the JDK up to 10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/allclasses-frame.html) or [in Guava itself](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/25.0-jre/api/docs/allclasses-frame.html).

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire `com.google.errorprone.annotations.Immutable`

Answer (score 1):

I believe that Error Prone is [hardcoded](https://github.com/google/error-prone/blob/04d4a498c840bf6a319a030245c41aa31cc2b1dd/core/src/main/java/com/google/errorprone/bugpatterns/ImmutableCollections.java) to recognize them as immutable. It seems reasonable to add them, though. Not sure how hard that would be.

Comment: It might make sense for `@Immutable` to have an optional `Class` element named something like `mutableType`, with the following example usage:`@Immutable(containerOf = "E", mutableType = List.class) class ImmutableList`.  `MUTABLE_TO_IMMUTABLE_CLASS_NAME_MAP` could be constructed by reading those annotations, and they might be useful elsewhere.